# Nginx : stat() failed (13: Permission denied) HTTP/1.1

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, vesta

- I'm using VESTA CPanel with Apache and Nginx web server, I see in error log

> 2016/01/12 05:13:49 [crit] 11115#0: *43127 stat()
>   "/home/user_example/web/example.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2014-Hyundai-Elantra-Coupe-Bestride-320x200.jpg"
>   failed (13: Permission denied), client: 116.193.67.106, server:
>   example.com, request: "GET
>   /wp-content/uploads/2014-Hyundai-Elantra-Coupe-Bestride-320x200.jpg
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer:
>   "http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php"

- I know that error happen when nginx dont have permission! But I try many ways to fix it as : remove disable_symlinks but it still have error !
- I'm using Wordpress 4.4.1 !

Comment: Try to give proper permissions for every file and folder up the directory tree.

Comment: every file and folder up I have chmod for +x but still have this error :(